# Is there a way to use the RtlSetProcessIsCritical function from the Windows API in Python?

Tags: python, c++, windows, winapi, process

I want to use the RtlSetProcessIsCritical function that sets a current process as critical but I really couldn't find a way to use it with Python.
Here is the example of it in C++:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef VOID(_stdcall* RtlSetProcessIsCritical) (
    IN BOOLEAN        NewValue,
    OUT PBOOLEAN OldValue,
    IN BOOLEAN     IsWinlogon);

BOOL ProcessIsCritical()
{
    HANDLE hDLL;
    RtlSetProcessIsCritical fSetCritical;

    hDLL = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
    if (hDLL != NULL)
    {
        (fSetCritical) = (RtlSetProcessIsCritical)GetProcAddress((HINSTANCE)hDLL, "RtlSetProcessIsCritical");
        if (!fSetCritical) return 0;
        fSetCritical(1, 0, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to make it work in Python?
Here is the link to an article that describes the `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` function pretty good: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43405/Protecting-Your-Process-with-RtlSetProcessIsCriti

Comment: Yes, it is possible to call C functions from Python.

Comment: This function isn't anywhere in pywin32 and I don't know exactly how to call it

Comment: You do know that this will crash the system if your process dies? Normal user processes should not call this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load ntdll.dll in python. Requires Pywin32 library.

```
import win32process
import win32api
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

ntdll = WinDLL("ntdll.dll")
ntdll.RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1,0,0)
```